# Swift UICollectionView Delegate perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview

I'm using an external delegate file to handle all a UICollectionView's processing and I'm struggling to get the collection view cell to perform a segue based on the selected cell, via the delegate file.

Here's what I currently have inside the delegate file:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let mainController = MainController()
    mainController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: cell)


}
```

and on the Main Controller I have:

```
override func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) {
    if identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let detailController = DetailController()
        self.present(detailController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <DetailController: 0x7fbed8e6e4b0> on <MainController: 0x7fbedda79830> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I thought I could call up the reference via the delegate and it would present the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference of `MainController` that you are trying to get like below is wrong.

```
let mainController = MainController()
```

This will not give you the loaded/previewing instance of the object instead of this it will create a new object of MainController for you which is not in the previewing Hierarchy. So you need an actual previewing instance.

**Solution**
Create a global object of of UIViewController type in your delegate class and pass you previewing class reference so that you may use it when you need.

Example.

```
class DelegateDataSource: NSObject {
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    //Other Methods/Objects that you need.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    if let mainController = viewController as? MainController {
         mainController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: cell)
    }



}
}

class MainController: UIViewController {

    var delegateDataSource: DelegateDataSource?
    func initializeDelegates() {
         //Initialize you datasource object and do some tasks that you need and then assign your current instance to this class like this.
         delegateDataSource.viewController = self
    }

}
```

Comment: delegates should be weak, to not cause retain cycle.... `weak var viewController: UIViewController?` also it would be best to decouple code by using protocol

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainController = MainController()
mainController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: cell)
```

This will not work, either use delegate pattern or use singleton pattern for your MainController.

Answer (score -1):

Only an already presented controller can present another controller. Is the class implementing `didSelectItemAt` a `UIViewController`? If so, why not just do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: cell)
}
```